# How can I make IntelliSense only open up when I tell it to instead of when I type?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

The fact that it opens every time I type just rubs me the wrong time. Most of the time I know what I want to type in and sometimes I'm making dumb mistakes because of IntelliSense opening up at the wrong time, ex. when I try to reference variable called 'dummy' that I just created like a line ago, but VisualStudio in its infinite wisdom tries to offer that I for sure meant constant, class or a namespace called DUMMY that is declared somewhere else in the code or even in third-party library.

I'd rather have "Intelli" Sense open up only when I explicitly tell it to, like with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Mine is in Italian but... Tools menu->Options and on the input box `Search options` write `intelli` and select your language. For me, the first option on the right is something like `Show completion list after typing a character`. Remove this check and with shortcut `CTRL+SPACE` you can force the intellisense to show.